# Map with Double Array get method returning null

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

"Map-Double[], Double-" is how the map is created - as a hash map.
trying to feed in a Double[] of [0.0, 0.0] into the map to get the value, but the value it returns is null.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] listed = input.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        Double[] key = new Double[2];
        Double value = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            if(i<2) {
                key[i] = Double.parseDouble(listed[i]);
            } else {
                value = Double.parseDouble(listed[i]);
            }
        }
```

This is everything important to the code, it just reads from a file and places it inside a HashMap.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: sorry Solved, check answer below in the comments

Comment: Please don't mutilate your question by removing information. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: it was more because it wasn't important in finding the answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays as `Double[]` don't have a `equals`/`hashcode` methods that considers the actual content of the array entries. These methods in array only match if you use the same instance.

So you can't use an array as key in a HashMap, using a `List<Double>` as key would work but has other problems. I would recomend a dedicated class with a custom `equals()`/`hashcode()` implemntation.

Using equls/hashcode with double is also highly problematic.

Comment: is there no other type of map that better allows for this?

Comment: As you didn't specify what you want to do thats hard to tell. One option is guava Table..

Comment: my problem is that none of the values on their own is unique to be a key, but i have to use a map unfortunately

Comment: Sounds like a usecase for a custom class with a custom equals/hashcode, if you really need decimals as keys. I would consider `BigDecimal` or long/int with fixed offset. Exact matching on double is really problematic.

Comment: don't worry i sovled it, its really tacky and just awful but i don't care. basically just had to loop through all the keys and check the given values against them one by one, i could use a linked hash map to order it and break out of the loop when its found to somewhat shorten the processing time.